# ajax jquery .net results in "The resource cannot be found."

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax

I'm trying to do a simple ajax call in .net

Any advice?

```
[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld()
{
    return "Hello World";
}
```

I call the webmethod in my browser like this:
    http://localhost.com/Ajax/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld

Which results in

> "The resource cannot be found."

Probably because of the url syntax.

My routes are setup like:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Ajax/");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

If I delete the `MapRoute`, the webcall works, but the rest of my website fails.

Any advice?

Update:
I changed to use a controller. When I call it with a url in my browser I hit my breakpoint in the controller. But not when I run this code:

```
    <div id="Result">
        Kig her!
    </div>



@section javascript {
    $(function () {
        $("#FirstReminder").datepicker();
        $("#EndDate").datepicker();
    });

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Add the page method call as an onclick handler for the div.
  $("#Result").click(function() {
    alert('kkk');
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "AjaxWorkflow/GetSteps",
      data: {workflowId: "1", workflowStep: "test"},
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(msg) {
        // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
        $("#Result").text(msg.d);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Update 2:
I solved it by changing the line to

```
          data: "{workflowId: '1', workflowStep: 'test'}",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using routing, I assume this is an MVC website? If so you should use an `ActionResult` in your controller instead of a `WebMethod`. Try this:

```
public string HelloWorld()
{
    return Content("Hello World");
}
```

You would then call this using jQuery on the following URL:  `http://localhost.com/[Controller]/HelloWorld`

Note, in the example here I am returning a string - as per your original example. It is also possible to return an object via JSON, using `return Json(obj);`

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem, but I'm not sure if my jquery code can call a controller

Comment: @Anders it can - the same as any anchor would. Also, don't forget to accept this answer if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

WebMethods belong to `ASP.NET WebForms` while the routing belongs to `ASP.NET MVC`. You'd better not mix the two technologies.

In this case most of the application seems to be ASP.NET MVC if after removing the routing everything stops working. That means that you want to replace the `WebMethod` with a `Controller Action`.

Comment: Thanks. Updated my answer with a new question :-)